# Angularjs - how to properly use ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `ng-repeat` and `ng-switch` on an angular app, but I'm having a small issue with the way they are printed.

Here's the code, so that it is clearer:

```
    <div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id">
      <div ng-switch-when="0">
         <p>{{data.id}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

the repeater works, the problem is that I have this result printed as final result:

```
<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id">
  <div ng-switch-when="0">
     <p>0</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id"></div>

<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id"></div>

<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id"></div>

<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id"></div>

<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-switch="data.id"></div>
```

The problem here is quite obvious: i don't want all those empty divs, but i want only one, the one matching `ng-switch-when` matching id = 0.

How can I do this? where is the best place t put `ng-repeat` so that it doesn't print empty containers?

I tried moving it in different positions, but I ended up always having empty elements created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if for this like given below-

```
<div class="test" ng-repeat="data in dataTest track by data.id" ng-if="data.id==0">
      <div >
         <p>{{data.id}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```